# Linq Where statements in If conditions VB.net

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am stuck in LINQ where I have to specify the where clauses based upon values of check boxes. I tried searching for answers but most of them are in C# and I am not very good at understanding it's syntax.

```
      Dim recs = From exp In db.exprevs
               Where exp.school_id = currentschool.school_id And exp.type = 1


    If chbid.IsChecked = True Then
        ''here I want to tell the query to filter where ID is something
    End If

    If chbname.IsChecked = True Then
        ''here I want to filter where name is something
    End If

    dgsearchresult.ItemsSource = recs
```

It would be very good if someone guides me how to filter the query further.

Comment: There's not enough info here to help at all.  What is the model for exprevs?  How do the chbid and chbname even relate to that model?  Is chbname checked supposed to over-ride the query of chbid?

Comment: ANDing multiple conditions together is as simple as chaining `Where` calls on your query, e.g. `recs = recs.Where(Function(exp) exp.ID = someValue)`.  You can do that as many times as you like.  If you want to OR the conditions then it's not so simple.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the best I can guess is he's trying to query Where exp.ID = (a textbox?) if chbid is checked and query Where exp.Name = (a textbox?) if chbname is checked.  So, that initial query is a waste but there's not enough info.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if you would have posted this as an answer I would have accepted it. It worked, I was missing the function(exp) part. Thank You so much.

Comment: @NathanChampion Yes that is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: I started posting an answer but decided that I didn't have enough information to be sure that it actually would address the issue. As I said, it will work for ANDing multiple conditions but not for ORing and I was sure which you wanted. Either way, I'm glad that you have a solution.

Comment: @NathanChampion, I don't think that the initial query is a waste. It seems like there are certain conditions that will always be applied so they are in the initial query. That makes sense. The optional conditions are then added as separate `Where` calls if and only if they are required. My doubt was whether each of those optional conditions involved their own `TextBox` and they needed to be ANDed or there was one `TextBox` for all of them and they needed to be ORed.

Comment: Sorry, I inferred it was an OR statement based on the context that was listed.  However, I do think it'd squeak a tad performance boost from merging the recs query into both If statements assuming it's one OR the other.  I assumed it was a search for (ID) or (name).  I think having both of those queries include the initial recs inside both would be marginally more efficient than trying to merge those after the fact.  Ex: (From exp In db.exprevs Where exp.school_id = currentschool.school_id And exp.type = 1 And exp.id = txtID) and an equivalent for chbname.  Though, it reduces readability.

Comment: LINQ is good at efficient SQL queries, not necessarily the generation of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney)'s comment on the post I was able to solve my problem. To filter something inside the if statement I had to write this short piece of code in my case.

```
    recs = recs.Where(Function(exp) exp.ID = txtID.text)
```